# In what circumstance is Materialize_Random set in allowedMode?

Tags: postgresql, set-returning-functions, postgresql-extensions, c

In PostgreSQL there is a field called `allowedMode` called `SFRM_Materialize_Random`

> The Tuplestore must be created with `randomAccess = true` if
> `SFRM_Materialize_Random` is set in `allowedModes`, but it can (and preferably
> should) be created with `randomAccess = false` if not.

In which case is this set?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be set when using a scroll cursor. The example below uses my module [`dump_fcinfo()`](https://github.com/EvanCarroll/pg-dump-fcinfo)

```
# BEGIN DEFERRABLE ;
BEGIN
# DECLARE foo SCROLL CURSOR FOR SELECT sfrm_materialize_preferred FROM dump_fcinfo();
DECLARE CURSOR
# FETCH ALL FROM foo;
-[ RECORD 1 ]--------------+--
sfrm_materialize_preferred | t
```

---

Thanks to RhodiumToad for the pointer. He goes on to explain,

> what happens in such cases is that if you do a fetch prior or fetch backward N on the cursor, the executor actually asks the tuplestore for prior rows, and that's only allowed if you specified random access when creating it so the materialize_random flag is just passing down the request for reverse scans made when initializing the plan many node types can't do backward scans at all, in which case the planner wedges in a Materialize node to protect them so if the function call is beneath such a node, materialize_random wouldn't be set even for a cursor plan